# django tastypie override url

Tags: django, tastypie

i have a tastypie auto generated url

```
/api/v1/categories/?format=json
```

i want only this particular url to get data from a view instead of tastypie resource.

the reason i want to do is this because all my clients are using this and don't want to change that.

i tried to put my url under

```
 url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
 url(r'^api/v1/categories/\?format=json','categories.views.raw_data'),
```

in urls.py

that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the order:

```
 url(r'^api/v1/categories/\?format=json','categories.views.raw_data'),
 url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
```

django looks for matches from top to bottom.

> > [How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Answer (score 0):

it can be done this way from tastypie instead of overriding it in urls.py by using override_urls in your resources

```
def override_urls(self):
    return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name,'categories.views.raw_data', name="categories_views_raw_data"),]
```